# Delete files that do not start with a date (GAS - Google Drive)

Tags: google-apps-script

Today the script deletes files that begin with a date that is earlier than today:

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var shift = new Date().getTime() + 1000*60*60*5
  var today = new Date(new Date(shift).toDateString()).getTime();
  var obj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var dateFromFilename = file.getName().substr(0, 10);
    if (/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/.test(dateFromFilename)) {
      var date = new Date(dateFromFilename).getTime();
      if (date < today) {
        obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated(), owner: file.getOwner().getEmail()});
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var email = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com";
  var obj = getOldFileIDs();
  obj.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.owner == email) {
      Drive.Files.remove(e.id);
    }
  });
};
```

I would like the script to parse also if there is any file that does not start the name with a date, if any, that it also deletes, so it will not happen to get old files saved in the folder just because it could not parse through a date at the beginning of the name

Correct way:
`2019/10/20 Europe Lille x PSG.pdf`

Delete if:
`Europe Lille x PSG.pdf`

What would I need to adjust and what would the script look like for it to do this analysis as well?

I tried to work with modifications on:

```
var dateFromFilename = file.getName().substr(0, 10);
    if (/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/.test(dateFromFilename)) {
```

But returned an error while trying to put an additional `if ( status = 204)` as an error alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to delete the files that the date is included in the filename and the date is less than today.
- You want to also delete the files that the date is NOT included in the filename.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- In your script, the if statement of `if (/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/.test(dateFromFilename)) {}` checks whether the date is included in the filename. I think that this can be used for achieving your goal.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

From:

```
if (/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/.test(dateFromFilename)) {
  var date = new Date(dateFromFilename).getTime();
  if (date < today) {
    obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated(), owner: file.getOwner().getEmail()});
  }
}
```

To:

```
if (/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/.test(dateFromFilename)) {
  var date = new Date(dateFromFilename).getTime();
  if (date < today) {
    obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated(), owner: file.getOwner().getEmail()});
  }
} else {
  obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated(), owner: file.getOwner().getEmail()});
}
```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.